# AngularJS - How do I write a pass information from controller to directive to another controller with the directive being modular and reusable?

Tags: angularjs

This is in AngularJS. The currently problem I am facing is this.

I have data that is available in a controller, let's called it C1. In the HTML contained by that controller is a button that is linked to a directive called D1. When the directive is fired, it injects HTML code that basically simulates a lightbox in a visual sense (but not modal). This lightbox is controlled by another controller, called C2.

What I want to do is that in C1, there is data that needs to be received by C2. I am thinking of using D1 as the bridge for C1 to fire up C2 so logically, data might have to travel through that? (Or does it? is there another possible and more effective/stable way?) The problem with D1 and C2 is that they have to be modular and have to be reused somewhere else.

Now the location used somewhere else, say another controller called C3, might not have the data located at the same scope as C1. This data that I need might be located in a child scope of the parent scope that uses this directive so I cannot just use scope.

Basically, how would I write a directive that is binded to a button element, when the button element is clicked, the proper data will be passed to the directive from the controller that contains the button, then the directive fires up and inserts the lightbox HTML code, and passes the data to the controller used by the light box? This has to be done without using scope as the data might or might not exist in the parent scope directly and without using services and the data does not exist in the HTML (It's like an object that contains a bundle of data)

Comment: Typically, using a service is the recommended way to communicate between controllers. See how `$modal` is implemented in [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). In general, controllers should not know about directives, since directives live in the View, and controllers are View-agnostic

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The canonical way to communicate between controllers is using a service. You can communicate between a controller and a directive passing a callback to the directive or broadcasting and listening to events. As currently stated this question is probably too broad - and I see close duplicates every single day (in fact I'm seeing a long list of related questions on the right).

Comment: I have suggested the use of a service, however, my supervisor recommended not using a service for this though for this, he wants a direct passing. I have seen other answers but most of them uses scope, controller, or attr. I do believe that scope is out of the possibility in this case since the data may or may not exist directly in the parent scope and can only be determined in the controller. IDK about using controller or attr though.

Comment: If your supervisor has a specific requirement that you are unfamiliar with, which is different from the canonical way to perform the task, perhaps they need to tell you more about what they are expecting and why?